# Mongodb aggregation $in field of array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

### document structure

session document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648b811a16bc2e0355b8289"),
    "title" : "test",
    "messages" : [
        {
            "authorId" : ObjectId("5648b89f2fc311bc39073993"), // <-- the users id
            "created" : ISODate("2015-11-15T16:51:29.652Z"),
            "message" : "<p>test</p>"
        }
    ]
}
```

user document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5648b89f2fc311bc39073993"),
"pic" : "karl.png",
"profile" : {
    "name" : "Karl Morrison"
}
```

### queries

first query:

```
var id = '5648b811a16bc2e0355b8289'; // <-- id for the session document
var session = // <-- returns the session document
    yield sessions.findOne({
        _id: id,
    });
```

second query (this is where I am stuck):

```
var sessionUsers =
        yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            users.col.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: {
                            '_id': {
                                '$in': session.messages.authorId // <--- here I need help! Need all of the authorId's in the session document from the previous query result.
                            }
                        }
                                },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id: 1,
                            pic: 1,
                            name: '$profile.name'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                function (err, res) {
                    if (err === null)
                        resolve(res);
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
```

### question

So I am trying to get all of the `authorId`'s into an array and feed that array into the `$in` of the second query, which should return an array full of elements with the fields of `_id`, `pic` and `name`.

So `sessionUsers` variable should look something like this:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648b89f2fc311bc39073993"),
    "pic" : "karl.png",
    "name" : "Karl Morrison"
},...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but I think you are trying to send an array of objects instead of an array of _id's behind your `$match`. You will need to get all `_id`'s in a simple array and use the result. You can use [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash). Here are the [docs](https://lodash.com) for more information.

The code below "plucks" all _id's from your session data.

```
var ids = _.pluck(session.messages, 'author‌Id');
```

Next, change the `$match` part to this:

```
{
    $match: {
        '_id': {
            '$in': ids
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You understand correctly, pluck function seems nice I'll look into it!

Comment: Hmm the following `var ids = _.pluck(session.messages, 'authorId');` echos with `console.log(JSON.stringify(ids));` the following: `[null]`

Comment: @KarlMorrison Strange. Have you checked session before using pluck?

Comment: Indeed I have! `console.log(JSON.stringify(session))` echos as it should: `{"_id":"5648c283026b46b03f5ca1df","title":"test","messages":[{"authorId":"5648c279026b46b03f5ca1d9","authorName":"Karl","created":"2015-11-15T17:36:03.439Z","message":"<p>test</p>"}]}
`

Comment: My bad! Use `_.pluck(session.messages, 'author‌Id');` instead :)

Comment: I saw the error beforehand ;) I however copy pasted anyway and it now all of a sudden it works, typical hah. Thanks for the library, it looks like it will ease a lot of things in the future!

Comment: @KarlMorrison No problem and have fun!